# How to handle promises inside the JSX in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

This is the first time I came across handling the promises inside the JSX in my React JS project.

Here is my component code.

```
import React from 'react';
import Sodexo from './Sodexo';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {withCookies} from 'react-cookie';

import ticketImg from './../../images/web-images/ticketrest.png';
import sodexImg from './../../images/web-images/sodexo.png';

import {selectMealVoucher} from './../../actions/paymentActions';
import {getSavedCard} from './../../utils/PaymentGateway';


class MealVoucher extends React.Component {

    checkCardSaved = async () => {
        const {cookies} = this.props.cookies;
        const card = await getSavedCard(cookies.id,cookies.token);
        const {sodexo} = card.data;

        return sodexo.length === 0 ? 0 : 1;
    }

    render() {
        const {sodexo, ticketrestaurant} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div className="col-md-1 col-sm-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input 
                                type="radio" 
                                name="mealvoucher"
                                {...sodexo.isActive ? {checked: true} : {}} 
                                onChange={() => this.props.selectMealVoucher('sodexo')}
                            />
                            <img src={sodexImg} height="30px" style={{marginLeft:'15px'}}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input 
                                type="radio" 
                                name="mealvoucher"
                                {...ticketrestaurant ? {checked: true} : {}} 
                                onChange={() => this.props.selectMealVoucher('ticketrestaurant')}
                            />
                            <img src={ticketImg} height="30px" style={{marginLeft:'15px'}} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {
                    sodexo.isActive ? (
                       this.checkCardSaved().then(res => {
                           res ? <Sodexo /> : ''
                       })
                    ): ''
                }

            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => state.paymentpage.paymentoption.mealvouchers;
const mapDispatchToProps = {selectMealVoucher};

export default withCookies(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(MealVoucher));
```

In the above, I am trying to call `checkSavedCard()` inside the JSX, but even if I am returning the `0` or `1` from `checkSavedCard()`, I see that promise is getting returned instead of `0` or `1`.

So I used `.then()` and tried to render another component depending on the value returned by the `checkSavedCard()`.

But, this isn't working and instead, I am getting an error message.

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]).
```

So, I came up with a different approach. 
I created one global variable and inside the `checkSavedCard()` instead of returning the value I am saving that value to the global variable and then inside the JSX I am checking for the value of that global variable.

This approach works fine for me.

Here is the working component code.

```
import React from 'react';
import Sodexo from './Sodexo';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {withCookies} from 'react-cookie';

import ticketImg from './../../images/web-images/ticketrest.png';
import sodexImg from './../../images/web-images/sodexo.png';

import {selectMealVoucher} from './../../actions/paymentActions';
import {getSavedCard} from './../../utils/PaymentGateway';


class MealVoucher extends React.Component {
    cardStatus;

    componentDidMount() {
        this.checkCardSaved();
    }

    checkCardSaved = async () => {
        const {cookies} = this.props.cookies;
        const card = await getSavedCard(cookies.id,cookies.token);
        const {sodexo} = card.data;

        this.cardStatus = sodexo.length === 0 ? 0 : 1;
    }

    render() {
        const {sodexo, ticketrestaurant} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div className="col-md-1 col-sm-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input 
                                type="radio" 
                                name="mealvoucher"
                                {...sodexo.isActive ? {checked: true} : {}} 
                                onChange={() => this.props.selectMealVoucher('sodexo')}
                            />
                            <img src={sodexImg} height="30px" style={{marginLeft:'15px'}}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input 
                                type="radio" 
                                name="mealvoucher"
                                {...ticketrestaurant ? {checked: true} : {}} 
                                onChange={() => this.props.selectMealVoucher('ticketrestaurant')}
                            />
                            <img src={ticketImg} height="30px" style={{marginLeft:'15px'}} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {
                    sodexo.isActive && this.cardStatus ? (
                       <Sodexo />
                    ): ''
                }

            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => state.paymentpage.paymentoption.mealvouchers;
const mapDispatchToProps = {selectMealVoucher};

export default withCookies(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(MealVoucher));
```

But I think this isn't a perfect solution, there might be something provided by React JS, to handle the promises inside the JSX.

I googled it but I didn't find any solution on this.

Comment: Can't you return promise in some method or `componentDidMount()` and set it's value/flag to state ? It will be less messy rather than having it in JSX. JSX is purely for UI rendering so making async calls there would cause some inproper data to handle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React can't render from the result of a Promise. You should update a value in the component's state and render based on the state's value. See my example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/1vzon8r4k4. A button click sets the state to `loading: true` (just to show the user something while they wait), then fires off an async call. When the async call finished, the state is updated to set `loading: false` and set the result of the async call to a value in the state. When the state is updated, the `render` function is automatically called and the UI is updated to reflect the state change.

```js
const fakePromise = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fakeResult = "Complete";
    setTimeout(() => resolve(fakeResult), 1000);
  });

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      result: null
    };

    this.startAsync = this.startAsync.bind(this);
  }

  startAsync() {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    });

    fakePromise().then(result =>
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        result
      })
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, result } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {!result &&
          !loading && (
            <div>
              <h1>Result Not Fetched</h1>
              <button onClick={this.startAsync} type="button">
                Fetch Result Async
              </button>
            </div>
          )}
        {loading && <h1>Fetching Result</h1>}
        {result && <h1>Result is: {result}</h1>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```